# javascript object undefined error

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have Dynamic AJAX JSON Response object Data variable

```
 var Data = {"categories":
    [
      {"Id":"2","CategoryName":"Womens"},
      {"Id":"3","CategoryName":"Mens"},{"Id":"4","CategoryName":"Kids"},
      {"Id":"5","CategoryName":"Home"},{"Id":"6","CategoryName":"Health and Beauty"},
      {"Id":"7","CategoryName":"Seasonal Events"},{"Id":"10","CategoryName":"Model Shots"},
      {"Id":"11","CategoryName":"Product Shots"},      
      {"Id":"12","CategoryName":"Accessories"},
      {"Id":"13","CategoryName":"Tops"},{"Id":"14","CategoryName":"Spuds"},
      {"Id":"15","CategoryName":"EVIAN"}
     ],
         "brands_cat":{
             "_bandCount":{"171": "BrandId" : "171", "ArchiveName": "HP",     
             "img_from_archive":"7"}
                      }
    }
  };
```

When i used in loop and check **undefined**, works fine

```
for(var i in Data.categories){
   if(typeof Data.categories[i] == 'undefined'){
       alert(i+"Cat undefined");
   }
}
```

But when i used typeof to check **undefined**,

```
for(var i in Data.categories){
       if(typeof Data.brands_cat._catCount[i].total == 'undefined'){
           alert(i+"Cat total undefined");
       }
    }
```

And it gave error

```
TypeError: Data.brands_cat._catCount is undefined
```

Is it possible to check multilevel JSON object undefined with typeof keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `_catCount` in `brands_cat`. So, change it like this

```
if (Data.brands_cat.hasOwnProperty("_catCount")) {
    for (var i in Data.brands_cat._catCount) {
        if(typeof Data.brands_cat._catCount[i].total == 'undefined') {
```

This code will iterate through `_catCount` only if it is found

Comment: There might have `_catCount`, it is category items count, so how i can prevent from error

Answer (score 0):

Within the example object you gave brands_cat does not always exist. When you iterate you need to check for the existence of that first prior to checking anything further down the object tree.